# GL_INVALID_OPERATION when calling glVertexAttribPointer

Tags: c, opengl, gtk

trying to follow this video tutorial: [YouTube: OpenGL Hello World Triangle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dyue3MzJDss) I've made the following code that doesn't work. But before, I don't follow the tutorial in 100%, just the OpenGL part. On this video the guy uses Qt when I am using Gtk, he also uses glew when I am using epoxy and he is programming in C++ on Windows when I am using C on Linux 4.12.12. The problem is that the call to glVertexAttribPointer gives me GL_INVALID_OPERATION. I can't really figure why.

Code:

```
#include <epoxy/gl.h>
#include <epoxy/glx.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void realize (GtkGLArea *area) {
  GLuint buffer;
  GLenum err;
  GLfloat vertices[] = {
    +0.0f, +1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,
    +1.0f, -1.0f
  };

  gtk_gl_area_make_current (area);
  //glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

  g_print("Call to glGenBuffers()\n");
  glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
  err = glGetError();
  if (err != GL_NO_ERROR) {
    g_print("Error detected: 0x%X\n", err);
  }

  g_print("Call to glBindBuffer()\n");
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  err = glGetError();
  if (err != GL_NO_ERROR) {
    g_print("Error detected: 0x%X\n", err);
  }
  g_print("Call to glBufferData()\n");
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  err = glGetError();
  if (err != GL_NO_ERROR) {
    g_print("Error detected: 0x%X\n", err);
  }

  g_print("Call to glEnableVertexAttribArray()\n");
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  err = glGetError();
  if (err != GL_NO_ERROR) {
    g_print("Error detected: 0x%X\n", err);
  }

  g_print("Call to glVertexAttribPointer()\n");
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
  err = glGetError();
  if (err != GL_NO_ERROR) {
    g_print("Error detected: 0x%X\n", err);
  }
}

static gboolean render (GtkGLArea *area, GdkGLContext *context) {
  //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  return FALSE;
}

static void activate (GtkApplication* app) {
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *glarea;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  glarea = gtk_gl_area_new ();
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "GL Window");
  gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 600, 400);
  gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_WINDOW (window), FALSE);
  g_signal_connect (glarea, "realize", G_CALLBACK (realize), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (glarea, "render", G_CALLBACK (render), NULL);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(window), glarea);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("local.gltest", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

Every noticed error with the code is nice to see.

Makefile for curious:

```
CLIBS = `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 epoxy`
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 epoxy`
DEPS = main.o
CC = gcc

run: run.bin
    ./run.bin

run.bin: $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CLIBS) $< $(CFLAGS) -o run.bin

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CLIBS) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@

clean:
    rm *.o *.bin
```

Comment: Which OpenGL version are you targeting? Using vertex attributes pointers without VAOs is deprecated in GL since a decade.

Comment: How to I check it? I don't really have any version in mind. I am completely new to OpenGL and I wanted to build something usable to tinker with.

Comment: `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` will tell you at least what you got. But the GL version you are targeting is not something you check, but something you _decide_ when starting the project.

Comment: glGetString() gives me "4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.0.6". Target? I don't really have anything in my mind, I was just trying to write some code to play with. I can say just as well that the version I target is the version I have on my computer.

Comment: Well, your code is definitively invalid in a core profile. However, the tutorial you linked uses legacy GL (which is deprecated since a decade).

Comment: Any better tutorials out there? I am looking for tutorial that could tech me the core OpenGL and how to draw triangle without VertexArrays. Every tutorial out there seems to be using VertexArray and the guy on that video says that they are not necessary, though useful.

Comment: Vertex Arrays aren't the issues. It is just that VAOs are mandatory in modern GL. Have a look at [Open.GL](https://open.gl/) and/or [Learning modern 3D Graphics Programming](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/).

Comment: Thanks for the links. So it is not possible to draw without VAOs anymore :/. OK